# THREE.TextureLoader load image fail "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is"

Tags: amazon-s3, three.js, cors, cross-domain

In threejs, I load an image from amazon s3 using the following code:

```js
var loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
loader.setCrossOrigin('');
loader.load(image_url,
    function ( texture ) {
        // do something with the texture
        var sphere = new THREE.Mesh(
            new THREE.SphereGeometry(radius, 20, 20),
            new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
                map: texture
            })
        );
        sphere.scale.x = -1;
        scene.add(sphere);
    },
    // Function called when download progresses
    function ( xhr ) {
        // console.log( (xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100) + '% loaded' );
    },
    // Function called when download errors
    function ( xhr ) {
        console.log( 'An error happened' );
    }
);
```

On amazon s3 bucket, i also configured CORS which enable all the origins to send cross-origin requests

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
    <CORSRule>
        <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedMethod>HEAD</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
    </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

According to some awnsers from similar question, I just need to set ***loader.setCrossOrigin('')***;
But it does not work. Error of CORS still occurs.

```js
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/.../test_image.jpg 
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access.
```

I'm using the latest version of ThreeJS.
Anyone can help? Thanks for all support.

## [Fixed]

It seems my photos uploaded before on AS3 are still affected by old CORS setting which does not allow to send cross origin request.
So, I remove old photos -> upload new and problem is solved.

Comment: This was the issue for almost a year for me :| thanks to you just re-uploaded and fixed it

Answer (score 0):

Open your config.php and find your base url... 
if you write like this `http://yoururl` 
change it like this `http://www.yoururl.com`

Hope its work this simple solution!! ;)